# downloading images from server, async or thread?

Tags: android, sql-server, multithreading, android-asynctask

My app is downloading images from a remote server,  I plan on using an async task to do it but I was wondering if a thread would prove to work better. I would much prefer an async task because it's easy ans simple, but I'll use a thread if I really have to, what do you think?

Thanks for all your answers, and what if I'm also uploading images as well, I don't think those libraries handle those, some sources tell me that a thread should rather be used for longer tasks, and an async should be used for tasks that will last 3 to 4 seconds? ????

Comment: AsyncTask is a type of thread. It performs an action on a background thread, and then provides an easy way to perform actions back on the main UI thread after the process has finished (like putting the downloaded image in an ImageView).

Comment: What about uploading images?? Some sources say a thread is better for longer processes

Comment: Since AsyncTask is a thread, that doesn't make sense. The only limitation to AsyncTasks is the number you can have running concurrently.

Comment: @dcharms http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html read the class overview,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Out of your two choices I would say use an Async Task as its basically just a nicer interface to threads and is generally better to work with.

Although, since you're using it to load images I would suggest you use the Picasso library as it loads everything asynchronously for you and also does caching which is a nice added extra. It's also by far the easiest library I've ever used.

You can find it here:
http://square.github.io/picasso/

Comment: What about uploading the images?

Comment: I think it really depends on where you are uploading the images to. Although I have had some success with this library: https://github.com/alexbbb/android-upload-service

Answer (score 0):

An async task is asynchronous, meaning it runs along with your UI code in a separate thread. So you are talking about two of the same things.

Answer (score 0):

An AsyncTask is a wrapper around a thread and callback, so using the thread directly will be more complicated.  You may prefer to use a library like [UniversalImageLoader](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader) instead.  It handles most or all of the general case image fetching, and can be configured to cache quite simply.

Answer (score 0):

Images, I suggest Volley NetworkImage. Search it on google for more info, examples are also available online on how to use it. It is fast, reliable and completely memory leak free.